# View with LEFT JOIN is Updatable?

Tags: join, view, mariadb

According to [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/inserting-and-updating-with-views/), a VIEW can't have a outer join to be updatable:

> A view cannot be used for updating if it uses any of the following:
>   ... an outer join ...

As far as i know, "outer join" include "left join" and "right join", right?
But when i test it (in mariaDB v10.1.25), it is updatable! What am I missing here?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1,t2;

CREATE TABLE t1(id INT, a TEXT);
INSERT INTO t1(id,a) VALUES (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');

CREATE TABLE t2(id INT, b TEXT);
INSERT INTO t2(id,b) VALUES (1,'+'),(1,'-'),(2,'*');

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v1 AS SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 USING(id);

#UPDATE v1 SET a='x' WHERE id=3; # worked
#UPDATE v1 SET a='y' WHERE b IS NULL; # worked
#UPDATE v1 SET b='y' WHERE b IS NULL; # worked! even so, it does not make sense and does not update anything

SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

Comment: My guess is that MySQL (or mariadb) was able to use the merge algorithm for creating the view and that supersedes the outer join restriction. But I would say this is a question for the MySQL / mariadb developers.

Comment: Well, I tried your queries in phpmyadmin.net's demo site and it did return the expected error message (#1288 - The target table v1 of the UPDATE is not updatable). So, can you pls be more specific as to which MySQL or mariadb version you have tested your queries against?

Comment: If I changed the database to mariadb, then the queries went through. So, MySQL behaves as advertised, but mariadb does not. So, let's remove MySQL from the question.

Comment: Ok! I removed the mysql tag too. So does it depends on the version of mariaDB?

Comment: I have no idea. The phmyadmin.net demo uses `10.1.26 MariaDB-0+deb9u1`, but the documentation does not mention any version dependency. So, I'm afraid you still need to ask the mariadb developers on this. Btw, checked in mariadb: the algorithm for the view is undefined - so much about my theory of using merge...

Comment: It also works on MySQL 5.5.42, not only on MariaDB, while it is not working on MySQL 5.7.21; I don't know about 5.6.x. It seems that at some point something changed. I would put MySQL back on your question.

Comment: I can confirm. VIEWs with LEFT JOIN work on old MySQL Versions (5.5.45). MySQL 8.0 doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

Some entries in the ChangeLogs.  (This is too long for a Comment; perhaps the Answer is buried in one of the links.)

----- 2015-08-03 5.7.8 Release Candidate -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

An assertion could be raised if a multiple-table UPDATE ( /doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html ) of a view, where the same column was used in the SET and JOIN clauses, was used as a prepared statement. (Bug #76962, Bug #21045724)
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76962

----- 2015-03-09 5.7.6 Milestone 16 -- Optimizer Notes -- -----

To handle a derived table (subquery in the FROM clause) or view reference, ...
`mysql> SET optimizer_switch = 'derived_merge=off';` ...
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59203

----- 2015-06-04 MariaDB 10.1.5 & 2015-05-07 MariaDB 10.0.18 & 2015-05-01 MariaDB 5.5.43 -- -- -----

MDEV-7613 : MariaDB 5.5.40 server crash on update table left join with a view 
http://localhost/kb/en/mariadb-5540-release-notes/

----- 2009-12-07 5.5.0 Milestone 2 & 2009-10-06 5.1.40 -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

A multiple-table UPDATE ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html ) involving a natural join and a mergeable view raised an assertion. (Bug #47150)
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47150

Note:  5.5 predates MariaDB 10.1, and the fix should be included; 5.7 comes after, so it won't be in 10.1.